# Minimise multiple labels at once in renpy

Tags: python, renpy

I have multiple labels in my code like this.

[image]

The only way to close them as far as I'm aware is to click the four arrows, one time each.

This isn't a problem with only four labels. But what if I have a hundred?

How can I 'mass close' all labels in my project?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please remove the python tag. The issue is solely in the `IDE` renpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode has a command called "Fold All" that'll do that. You can access it by hitting Ctrl + P and then typing ">Fold All" into the command palette.

[image]

You can also play around with the keyboard shortcut that does this by hitting the gear to the right of "Fold All" in the command palette.  It says online the default keybindings are "Ctrl+K" and "Ctrl+0", but I think I've since migrated those to other things on mine so I can't verify that on my end...